# jQuery: the difference between "live" and "on" for a function

Tags: jquery

I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on)

and had a question that I didn't think it answered.  Why does this work:

```
$('#threeButtons').live('click', '.markAsSpam', function() {
     // do some stuff
});
```

but this doesn't:

```
$('#threeButtons').on('click', '.markAsSpam', function() {
     // do some stuff
});
```

I see the parameters are different, but I am following the example of how to use .on.  At least as it applies to my example.

My DOM looks like

```
<div id="threeButtons">
     <a href="#" class="markAsSpam">Spam</a>
     ...
</div>
```

I need to use .live or .on because I am dealing with HTML that appended in the DOM.  Also, my .live example only works the first time. What do I need to make it work on successive tries, without refreshing the page.  I'm using jQuery 1.7 and want to use .on, since .live has been deprecated.

Comment: You're misusing the second argument to `.live()`. It's meant to set data on the event object. jQuery's `live()`, `delegate()` and `on()` methods use *event delegation*. It would be worth learning about it before using them. *(The `.on()` method only uses event delegation when passing providing a second argument like you did in the second example.)*

Comment: ...`.live()` is implicit event delegation with the handler on the `document`. This was an unfortunate decision... hence the deprecation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> `.live( events, data, handler(eventObject) )`

So the following code will simply register a live click event for `#threeButtons` which will receive an additional argument `.markAsSpam`:

```
$('#threeButtons').live('click', '.markAsSpam', function() {
     // do some stuff
});
```

When using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) however, you create a delegate where the `click` handler is bound on `#threeButtons` but the event will only fire if the clicked element matches the `.markAsSpam` selector.

Comment: Gotcha.  But why does it work only once.  The spam button is on every item.  These are added in a for loop and then appended.

Comment: Is `#threeButtons` added/recreated dynamically? If yes you need to use a different selector. Use `$(document).on(...)` if you want to replicate the behaviour of `.live()`

Comment: Interesting to note that as of JQuery 1.7 live, bind, delegate all now just call the .on() method.