# How to access input elements which were created by jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, input

I want to create an upload form, which always presents a new file input, when filled out. I tried to make this work by creating new inputs but it just works once.

Here is the code:

```
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script></head>
<body><form>
  <div id="to"></div>
  ---
  <div id="from"><input type="file" class="new"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.new').change(function() {
    $('.new').appendTo('#to').removeClass('new');
    $('#from').append('<input type="file" class="new">');
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: try this  $('#from').append('<input></input'>.attr('type','file')class="new">');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.new').live('change',function() {
    $('.new').appendTo('#to').removeClass('new');
    $('#from').append('<input type="file" class="new">');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Use of the .live() method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on

Comment: Try updating your jquery library

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.new').on('change',function() {
    $('.new').appendTo('#to').removeClass('new');
    $('#from').append('<input type="file" class="new">');
  });
</script>
```

use `on`

Comment: +1 This will definitely work..if we use the latest jquery library

Answer (score 0):

HIya 2 **working demos for you** : http://jsfiddle.net/UxyMw/   or http://jsfiddle.net/UxyMw/1/

both works fine:

**code:**

```
$('.new').on("change",function() {
    $('.new').appendTo('#to').removeClass('new');
    $('#from').append('<input type="file" class="new">');
  });​
```

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/UxyMw/3/