# JQuery Mobile: Access IDs after manipulating DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm using an AJAX request to add some pages into my JQuery mobile site.
But after adding buttons I cannot access those using the class I set before.
Is there a way to inform JQuery that I updated the DOM and that there are new buttons with the class?

adding the button:

```
echo "<a data-role=\"button\" class=\"delbtn\" data-transition=\"fade\" data-icon=\"delete\">Delete</a>";
```

accessing the button:

```
$(".delbtn").click(function(){
  //some action.. 
});
```

Comment: please share some code. Are you using the same id for multiple buttons?

Comment: There is generally no problem accessing newly added objects by id so you will have to show us more for us to have any idea what might be going on.  Show us the HTML.  Do you have duplicate IDs?

Comment: sorry. I'm using classes. I try to access the buttons via the click() function.

Comment: please use `.live` or `.on` to bind the click event. refer to the docs for more info.

Comment: Use the live() / on() methods tonprovide the click event om inserted elements!

Comment: could somebody add an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to bind a live event handler ([jQuery ON](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) because your buttons are added dynamically

```
$(document).on("click",".delbtn", function(){
  //some action.. 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/MEXhE/1/

```
$(".delbtn").live('click',function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: where's the difference to `on()` ?

Comment: if you're using jquery 1.7 onwards you should use `.on` instead of `.live`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on