# jQuery live() vs on() in 1.7+

Tags: jquery, live

I know as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. So this is what I came up with:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#list', function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Which pretty much does the trick and is equivalent to:

```
$('#list').live('click', function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

They both return the **#list** jQuery object, which is what I wanted.
The problem is however when I pass a jQuery object as a second parameter, instead of string (which happens quite often), eg:

```
var list = $('#list');
$(document.body).on('click', list, function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

The console returns **$(body)** jQuery object. Which is useless in that point. ;)
Any ideas?

EDIT: The problem here is **NOT** how to access the affected object $('#list') from example 1 and 2, but how to access it in example 3.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on

Comment: Not really I think. I desribed my problem concerning accessing the event affected object, not the difference between those two methods.

Comment: The console is returning exactly what is expected $(this) refers to document.body in this case

Comment: Absolutely. But how do I access affected object(s) (assuming there are sibling for example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty clear answer you will find in the official [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> Use of the .live() method is no longer recommended since later
>   versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its
>   drawbacks. In particular, the following issues arise with the use of
>   .live():
>
> - jQuery attempts to retrieve the elements specified by the selector before calling the `.live()` method, which may be
>     time-consuming on large documents.
> - Chaining methods is not supported. For example, `$("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... );`  is
>     *not* valid and does not work as expected.
> - Since all `.live()` events are attached at the `document` element, events take the longest and slowest
>     possible path before they are handled.
> - Calling [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation)
>     in the event handler is ineffective in stopping event handlers
>     attached lower in the document; the event has already propagated to
>     `document`.
> - The `.live()` method interacts with other event methods in ways that can be surprising, e.g.,
>     `$(document).unbind("click")` removes all click handlers
>     attached by any call to `.live()`!

Answer (score 1):

It's simply incorrect to pass an object as the second parameter to `on`.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

`.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )`

It asks for a selector and not a jQuery object, so you need to use:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#list', function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: So how do I access affected selector (if for example there are siblings)?

Comment: As in, if there are other list elements that would be matched by the selector? `$(this)` will refer to the one that was clicked.

Comment: I've added an edit in the first post, hope I'll that'll highlight the problem. ("The problem here is NOT how to access the affected object $('#list') from example 1 and 2, but how to access it in example 3.")

Comment: I see. The answer remains the same; you can't. The second argument `on` takes is a selector and not an object.

Comment: Uhm, I see. Doesn't it deny the DRY concept?