# What to use instead of .live() for elements added after event declaration (jQuery v1.9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery: on vs live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864476/jquery-on-vs-live)

I used to use **.live()** method when I have **dynamically created objects** by javascript, because at the time I declare the event listener to a click for instance, the element isn't in the DOM yet, so when the element is added dynamically by an user action, the .live('click') method would do the trick.

But, in jQuery v1.9.0, there's no live method, the documentation advises to use **.on()** instead, but that doesn't work in this kind of example ...

Here is a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/C3DLQ/.

It will only work if you set the jQuery to 1.8.3 or the Migrate Plugin.

```
$("#create").click(function(){
    $('body').append($('<div id="test" class="btn">click me<div>'));
});

$("#test").on("click", function(){
    alert("worked!"); 
});
```

I actually tested other methods like **delegate()** and **bind()**, but none worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686326/jquery-live-vs-on-in-1-7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function

Comment: Hi @undefined, those questions, doesn't answer to my question...

Comment: Hi, I believe they do. http://jsfiddle.net/Y4y43/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is not working is that `test` did not exist when the javascript first ran.  If you attach the on event to the parent element and filter it to `#test`, then it will work as expected.

```
$("body").on("click", "#test", function(){
    alert("worked!"); 
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C3DLQ/4/

Comment: Korner, but thats the point! I want to insert the element after the event declaration... dynamicly, with live, that is possible ... but live isn't avaiable anymore ...

Comment: So you attach the event handler to the parent and filter it, as I have done in this exmaple.

Comment: I updated the code a bit to show you could attach the event to the body (instead of the document), but filter it to the selector of the second parameter `#test`

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand at first, I get it now, thanks

Comment: You should not use multiple IDs in one document. This is very bad practice.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst I agree 100%.  If you will be appending multiples, generate unique ids or don't use ids at all and use a class to reference the items.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach it to the document and specify a selector, like so:

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function(){
    alert("worked!"); 
});
```

The `#test` element wasn't returned on your initial selector query, so no event was attached. Attaching it to the `document` element and specifying a selector to use will make it work when new elements are added to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because you are using multiple instances of one ID. Use classes instead when selecting more than one element.

```
$('#create').click(function() {
    $('body').append($('<div class="btn test">click me<div>'));
});
```

Also you need to bind the click to the document and filter the element to `.test` like this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function() {
    alert('worked!'); 
});
```

Comment: I changed the fiddle, and that's not the solution ...