# jQuery Replace only the class of an element without changing other content

Tags: jquery

I have a player that is triggered with jQuery. I may have several players on a single page but a single 'miniPlayer' in the toolbar. The player toolbar needs to play/pause etc if another player event is triggered. For this to happen I need to only replace the class inside the player element.

The player in the toolbar has an id of #miniPlayer and all other players will just be #player, this is for styles. Because of this I can only replace the class within the element so that the styles are not changed for the miniPlayer if a button in the player is clicked, or visa versa.

Mini Player (play);

```
<a id="miniControls" class="play" href="" title=""></a>
```

Will become;

```
<a id="miniControls" class="pause" href="" title=""></a>
```

Onclick of either the miniPlayer pause button or the normal player pause button.

Normal Player (play);

```
<a id="controls" class="play" href="" title=""></a>
```

Will become;

```
<a id="controls" class="pause" href="" title=""></a>
```

Onclick of either the miniPlayer pause button or the normal player pause button.

The jQuery I have at the moment will replace the miniplayer, if the normal player (play) is clicked with;

```
<a id="controls" class="pause" href="" title=""></a>
```

But the id needs to stay as miniControls for the styles. This will be the opposite but same problem if the miniPlayer is clicked.

Play/Pause functions in jquery script (only works for miniPlayer at the moment):

```
play.live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    song.play();

    $('.play').replaceWith('<a id="miniControls" class="pause" href="" title=""></a>');

    $('.seek').attr('max',song.duration);
});

pause.live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    song.pause();
    $('.pause').replaceWith('<a id="miniControls" class="play" href="" title=""></a>');

});
```

Is there a way to only replace the class so i'd just replace $('.pause') with $('.play') instead of the whole `<a>` tag. I've had a look on the jquery website but couldn't find anything. Maybe I am looking at it at the wrong angle.

Comment: Please do not use `.live()`. You should rather use event delegation with `.on()`, see this discussion [What's the difference between jQuery .live() and .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#miniControls').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hasClass('play') ? song.pause():song.play();
    $(this).toggleClass('play pause');
});
```

You can greatly reduce your code by using something like the above example. In this case you would use `.toggleClass()` to switch between the play and pauses classes and also use `.hasClass()` to determine which action to perform.

Comment: That just triggers a page reload

Comment: I thought that too but it does. I removed all other code from the .js file and checked all the markup had the right id's/classes with no avail

Comment: I also stumbled in a situation where `e.preventDefault()` was not suffice for the browser to not open the link. I also had to `return false;` in the event handler. This "following the link" is the reload of the page.

Comment: On another note: I think you meant `$(this).hasClass('play') ? song.pause() : song.play();` in your code example. ;-)

Comment: @apfelbox - correct, fixed. Although judging from the OP's other issues it doesn't seem to be a major problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery's .toggleClass() function:

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/