# Jquery document.on event

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between  these event handling

```
       $(document).on("click","selector",function(event){

        });
```

and

```
       $("selector").live("click",function(event){

       });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between jQuery .live() and .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on)

Comment: they are quite identical in result, except that `live` is deprecated on newer jQuery version

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple selector in both types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the event is attached on "document" DOM, right ?

In the second case, the event is attached on the "selector" DOM, right ?

The first was chosen by jQuery : just few elements catch the events in the solution 1/ (document can be attached to every events), but in the solution 2/ many elements of the page are in memory, attached to events.

For instance :

```
$(".test").live("click",function(event){"do something"}
$(".test1").live("click",function(event){"do something1"}
$(".test2").live("click",function(event){"do something2"}
```

3 elements are listening to the *click* event, right ?

Now these elements are in a div "myDiv"

```
$("#myDiv").on("click",".test",function(event){"do something"}
$("#myDiv").on("click",".test",function(event){"do something"}
$("#myDiv").on("click",".test",function(event){"do something"}
```

Only myDiv is attached the event *click* by bubbling !

But don't use *on* on the *document* tag, use this function on a few global div !

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `.on()` method is the actual event listener which you should use.

Second  `.live()` used to be the #1 but was deprecated in the last versions so you should not use it anymore.

The work the same way, you can call it the same way.