# traversing not working over the table within the div

Tags: jquery, ajax

im trying to empty a table within a div using .children() then append the new result of ajax but my traversing is not working. my tr is dynamically created using ajax with another function so that the i call the function inside the success ajax of click to reload the request again to make it like reloading the div again. plss help guys..

html

```
<div id="curr-elem">
  <div class="box-header">
     <h3>Elementary Subject</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="curr-elem-content">
      <table id="curr-elem-tble">

        <tr>
          <td>
            <lable>Subject:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="a" rel="1" name="subject[0]"></lable>
          </td>
          <td>
             <input id="activate[0]" class="button active modal2 inactiveButton" type="button" disabled="disabled" value="Apply" name="active" rel="#loading-window">
             <input id="inactivate[0]" class="button inactive modal2 " type="button" value="Remove from list" name="active" rel="#loading-window">
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
            <lable>Subject:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="ssssss" rel="8" name="subject[1]"></lable>
          </td>
          <td>
             <input id="activate[1]" class="button active modal2 inactiveButton" type="button" disabled="disabled" value="Apply" name="active" rel="#loading-window">
             <input id="inactivate[1]" class="button inactive modal2 " type="button" value="Remove from list" name="active" rel="#loading-window">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <lable>Subject:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="alvin" rel="9" name="subject[2]"></lable>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="activate[2]" class="button active modal2 inactiveButton" type="button" disabled="disabled" value="Apply" name="active" rel="#loading-window">
            <input id="inactivate[2]" class="button inactive modal2 " type="button" value="Remove from list" name="active" rel="#loading-window">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <lable>Subject:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="ronniel" rel="10" name="subject[3]"></lable>
           </td>
           <td>
             <input id="activate[3]" class="button active modal2 inactiveButton" type="button" disabled="disabled" value="Apply" name="active" rel="#loading-window">
             <input id="inactivate[3]" class="button inactive modal2 " type="button" value="Remove from list" name="active" rel="#loading-window">
           </td>
        </tr>

  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

ajax:

```
  $('.active').live('click',function (){

            var prev = $(this).parent().prev().find('input[type=text]');
              var valText = $(prev).val();

              var relVal = $(this).parent().prev().find('input[type=text]').attr('rel');

                 var div = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');





               $.ajax({
                          type:'POST',
                          url:'add_subject.php',
                     dataType:'json',
                         data:{'func_numbr':'7','subjct_name':valText,'subjct_id':relVal},
                      success:function (data){
                        $('#mask2').hide();

                        $('#loading-window').hide();

                        $("[id*="+div+"]").children().children().find("table").html("");

                        load_elementary();




                      }     
               });



       });


function load_elementary(){ 
       var html;

                $.ajax({
                          type:'POST',
                          url:'add_subject.php',
                     dataType:'json',
                         data:{'func_numbr':'2'},
                      success:function (data){
                        var activator;

                        var disabler;
                         var counter_sub = 0 ;

                         $.each(data, function(i, item) {

                          if(data[i].subj_status == "0"){

                            classToAddInactve = "inactiveButton";
                            DisableInactve = "disabled=\"disabled\""
                            classToAddActve   = "";
                            DisableActve = ""
                           }

                           else{

                            classToAddInactve = ""
                             DisableInactve = ""
                             classToAddActve   = "inactiveButton";
                             DisableActve = "disabled=\"disabled\""
                           }




                          html = "<tr>";

                          html += "<td><lable>Subject: </label><input type='text' name='subject["+counter_sub+"]' rel='"+data[i].subj_id+"' value='"+data[i].subj_name+"' readonly='readonly'></td>";
                          html += "<td><input type='button' rel='#loading-window' id='activate["+counter_sub+"]' name='active' class='button active modal2 "+classToAddActve+"' value='Apply' "+DisableActve+"> ";
                          html += "<input type='button' rel='#loading-window' id='inactivate["+counter_sub+"]' name='active' class='button inactive modal2 "+classToAddInactve+"' value='Remove from list' "+DisableInactve+"></td>";
                          html += "</tr>";

                 $('#curr-elem-tble').append(html);

                 counter_sub = counter_sub +1;
                });
                      }     
               });
}
```

load_elementary();

Comment: I'm having a bit of a time following, so I'll just make some observations:  Looks like two main javascript blocks.. one a click method on elements with the class of "active", the other is a function called load_elementary.  The latter is never called, and the former is attached to elements that are "disabled" which means that the click will never execute.

Comment: i edit it i forget to put the  load_elementary(); after the function was made.

Comment: Are you always trying to clear the contents of curr-elem-tble?  If so, you could just use $("#curr-elem-tble").html('');  If not, I'm not sure I follow where the new "tables" get added.

Comment: yeah. its not the only tble that would use the click thats why it needs to be dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments on your HTML markup.

1. Assuming you have control of the markup, make your life easier by adding classes to the containing div and the dynamic table.
2. You have your `<label>` elements currently defined as `<lable>` elements, which may cause problems in the long run (I've taken the liberty of calling them `<label>` instead).
3. Is there really a point in every button having the same value for the `name` attribute?
4. Speaking of the `name` attribute... unless you are actually going to post the form using a `<input type="submit">` or a `.submit()`, you may as well not use the `name` attribute. It's virtually useless in JavaScript (as there are far more efficient ways to write your code without using it, unless you have radio buttons... then it's a different story altogether).

HTML:

```
<div id="curr-elem" class="container">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3>Elementary Subject</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="curr-elem-content">
        <table id="curr-elem-tble" class="dynamic-table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="subject_0">Subject:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="subject_0" name="subject[0]" readonly="readonly" value="a" rel="1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="activate_0" name="active" class="button active modal2 inactiveButton" disabled="disabled" value="Apply" rel="#loading-window">
                    <input type="button" id="inactivate_0" name="active" class="button inactive modal2" value="Remove from list" rel="#loading-window">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="subject_1">Subject:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="subject_1" name="subject[1]" readonly="readonly" value="ssssss" rel="8">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="activate_1" name="active" class="button active modal2 inactiveButton" disabled="disabled" value="Apply" rel="#loading-window">
                    <input type="button" id="inactivate_1" name="active" class="button inactive modal2" value="Remove from list" rel="#loading-window">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="subject_2">Subject:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="subject_2" name="subject[2]" readonly="readonly" value="alvin" rel="9">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="activate_2" name="active" class="button active modal2 inactiveButton" disabled="disabled" value="Apply" rel="#loading-window">
                    <input type="button" id="inactivate_2" name="active" class="button inactive modal2" value="Remove from list" rel="#loading-window">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="subject_3">Subject:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="subject_3" name="subject[3]" readonly="readonly" value="ronniel" rel="10">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="activate_3" name="active" class="button active modal2 inactiveButton" disabled="disabled" value="Apply" rel="#loading-window">
                    <input type="button" id="inactivate_3" name="active" class="button inactive modal2" value="Remove from list" rel="#loading-window">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Regarding your JavaScript:

1. `.live()` [is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) as of jQuery 1.7. You should use `.on()` if you are using 1.7 or higher. If you are using a lower version, you should be using `.delegate()` instead. There are [several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on) not to use `.live()`.
2. Generally speaking, it's good practice to define your functions before you use them. Since you're using AJAX here it's not a big deal, but you may want to start writing your code like that.
3. Generally speaking, you should build your DOM elements as actual elements and then append them, rather than building an HTML string by hand and then using the `.innerHTML` property or the jQuery `.html()` method. Long chains of string concatenation get messy and
   it's rather easy to make a mistake (and with jQuery, building actual elements is rather simple).

JavaScript:

```
//define load_elementary function
var load_elementary = function load_elementary(table) {
    $.ajax({
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "add_subject.php",
        "dataType": "json",
        "data": {
            "func_numbr": "2"
        },
        "success": function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var tbody = $('<tbody />'),
                tr = $('<tr />'),
                td = $('<td />'),
                counter_sub = 0;
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var label = $('<label />'),
                    textbox = $('<input />').attr('type', 'text').prop('readonly', true),
                    button = $('<input />').attr('type', 'button'),
                    row = tr.clone(),
                    cell = td.clone(),
                    subjIsNotActive = data[i].subj_status !== "0",
                    subjIsActive = !subjIsNotActive;
                //make first cell
                cell.append(label.attr('for', 'subject_' + counter_sub).text('Subject: '));
                cell.append(textbox.attr({
                    "id": "subject_" + counter_sub,
                    "name": "subject[" + counter_sub + "]",
                    "rel": data[i].subj_id
                }).val(data[i].subj_name));
                //append first cell
                row.append(cell);
                //make second cell
                cell = td.clone();
                cell.append(button.addClass('button active modal2').toggleClass('inactiveButton', subjIsNotActive).prop('disabled', subjIsNotActive).attr({
                    "id": "activate_" + counter_sub,
                    "name": "active",
                    "rel": "#loading-window"
                }).val('Apply'));
                cell.append(button.addClass('button inactive modal2').toggleClass('inactiveButton', subjIsActive).prop('disabled', subjIsActive).attr({
                    "id": "inactivate_" + counter_sub,
                    "name": "active",
                    "rel": "#loading-window"
                }).val('Remove from list'));
                //append second cell
                row.append(cell);
                //append row to tbody
                tbody.append(row);
                counter_sub += 1;
            });
            //empty current contents and then append tbody to table
            table.empty().append(tbody);
        }
    });
};
//add click handlers
$('.active').on('click', function () {
    var self = $(this),
        subj = self.parent().prev().find('input[type=text]'),
        text = subj.val(),
        rel = subj.attr('rel'),
        container = self.parents('div.container');
    $.ajax({
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "add_subject.php",
        "dataType": 'json',
        "data": {
            "func_numbr": "7",
            "subjct_name": text,
            "subjct_id": rel
        },
        "success": function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var table = container.find('table.dynamic-table');
            $('#mask2').hide();
            $('#loading-window').hide();
            load_elementary(table);
        }
    });
});
```