# How can I bind a function to a click on any ajax generated list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click, bind

I have a simple unordered list that is generated via `$.ajax`...

```
<ul id="simpleList"></ul>
```

After an ajax response it looks something like this:

```
<ul id="simpleList">
    <li id="aaa">list item aaa</li>
    <li id="bbb">list item bbb</li>
    <li id="ccc">list item ccc</li>
</ul>
```

I need to move clicked list items from this list to another list (`#selectedList`).

Normally I'd use the `.click` function to handle this, but since the initial list items are created on the fly via an ajax call I've started using `.live`, but I'm still not able to get it to work.  Here's an example of where I'm at so far.

```
$('#simpleList > li').live('click', function() {
    console.log('click registered');
    var contents = $(this).html();
    var listId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).remove();
    $('#selectedList').show();
    $('#selectedList').append('<li id="' + listId + '">' + contents + '</li>');
});
```

I'm expecting an end result like: (assuming the `#aaa` list item was clicked)

```
<ul id="simpleList">
    <li id="bbb">list item bbb</li>
    <li id="ccc">list item ccc</li>
</ul>
<ul id="selectedList">
    <li id="aaa">list item aaa</li>
</ul>
```

But instead nothing happens at all (not even a console log).  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `.live()` is deprecated [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is preferred

```
$('#simpleList').on('click', 'li', function() {
    console.log('click registered');
    var contents = $(this).html();
    var listId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).remove();
    $('#selectedList').show();
    $('#selectedList').append('<li id="' + listId + '">' + contents + '</li>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If `#simpleList` is on the page when you bind your events and doesn't go away, you could do

```
$('#simpleList').on('click', 'li', myFunction);
```

If it's not, you should either pick a parent element that is or you can wire it up to `$(document)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly move them to the other list by using [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$('#simpleList').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('#selectedList').append(this);
});
```

As everyone else said [use `.on()` for a delegated event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on). `.on()` will work for future as well as for current elements.

[See it here!](http://jsfiddle.net/JzsXN/)

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using `on` instead of live. You can also easily move the node from one parent to another using `append()`.  So it might look like this:

```
$('#simpleList').on('click','li', function() {
    console.log('click registered');
    $('#selectedList').append(this).show();
});
```

Comment: With every edit your answer just becomes like mine. Now, you are just one edit away from it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `on` instead of `live`. [Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on).

Also, you will need to call your code after the ajax call has succeeded, something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someUrl',                
    success: function (html) {
       $('#simpleList > li').on('click', function() {
        console.log('click registered');
        var contents = $(this).html();
        var listId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).remove();
        $('#selectedList').show();
        $('#selectedList').append('<li id="' + listId + '">' + contents + '</li>');
    });
    }
});
```

**Update: You can move it with less code**
(see [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) - untested)

```
$('#simpleList > li').on('click', function() {    
            $(this).appendTo('#selectedList)
}
```