# what is the usage of $("#element").on("click", function(event){ }); in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie to `jquery` and I would like to know the difference between a

```
$("#element").on("click", function(event){ });
```

and

```
$("#element").live("click", function(event){ });
```

function.

Comment: Remember to search before asking questions. Chances are the question, or similar, has already been asked.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on

Answer (score 0):

Well for one `$.live()` is deprecated as of 1.7.

Also for more details you can check this answer:
[What's the difference between jQuery .live() and .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on)

Comment: It's better to flag as duplicate than post a redundant answer linking to the duplicate question.

Comment: sorry about that, didn't know that it should be marked as duplicate. Also thanks for editing the format

Comment: So if i create a dom element after the above function , it will work without any problems , i had a bug that sometimes its not working as i have to give the same function right after the dom creation , how is that happened ?