# Add .datetimepicker to inputbox on load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using a model to load in another page. On the page should be a date picker but it's not showing up. If I just load the page without using the model the date picker works fine.

I realise that because the element I'm trying to bind to doesn't exist yet I need some extra Jquery to bind the .datetimepicker to the element once it's loaded.

```
         $("#EditContentLog1bt").live("click", function () {
                alert("test1");
            $("#datepick").ready(function () {
                alert("test2");
                $("#datepick").datetimepicker({
                    pickTime: false,
                       format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
                });
            });
        });
```

I've tried using .load rather than .ready but with .load I don't get to the second alert. With .ready I get to the second alert but the datepicker still doesn't work.

Html:

```
  <div class="control-group">
    <label for="followup" class="control-label">Date</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div id="datepick" class="input-append date">
            <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($contactLog->follow_up_date)); ?>">
            <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="followup" class="control-label">Time</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div id="timepick" class="input-append date">
            <input type="text" name="time" value="<?php echo date('H:i', strtotime($contactLog->follow_up_date)); ?>">
            <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't seem to be a z-index issue as I've got the datepicker working in another model but only by using .click rather than .load/.ready.

This is now the model gets called:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="EditContentLog1bt" href="<?php echo site_url('manager/editContactLog/' . base64_encode($this->encrypt->encode($log->id))); ?>" class="btn btn-primary contactLog">Edit</a>
```

And here's the html for the model:

```
<div id="myModalform" style="width:700px; margin-left:-380px;" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-body">
   <p>One fine body…</p>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: `.live()` is depreciated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9

Comment: What would you suggest I use instead?

Comment: Use `.on` like `$("#EditContentLog1bt").on("click", function () {` for more info check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on)

Comment: are youy using ajax or post to get the content of modal ??

Comment: I'm just using the built in Boot Strap function, I'll add the code shortly.

Comment: you are using default modal of bootstrap which is called from the HTml...i recommned you to use javascript to open the modal.. that should be there in the documentation of bootstrap and call `datetimepicker` after the modal opens

Comment: First, am not sure but is it correct to use the id of div rather than using id of input element ?
Also u can write the datetime script inside the html file which is getting loaded in modal. This way it should work

Comment: Jigar I thought that was odd as well but I'm following the instructions for the plugin I'm using. I believe I'v resolved the issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(function() {

$("#open_popup").click(function(){
$("#date").datepicker();
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      height:300,
        width:400 ,
        modal: true});
})

 });
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/4pE9X/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
    $("#datepick").datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    });
});
```