# jquery change() dont trigger on new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger elements while my `Checkbox` is checked or not checked.
it works perfectly fine with :

```
$('.myCheckbox:checkbox').change(function () {
//..
}
```

the thing is, that if I create a new checkbox on client, the `.change()` doesnt trigger.

I tried also :

```
$('.myCheckbox:checkbox').live('change',function () {
```

and it doesnt work as well..

does anyone knows whats wrong ?

Comment: What version of jquery? you probably want .on()

Comment: Im using 1.8.3 version

Comment: Yep, you need to use `.on`. `.live` is deprecated. [Here's the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey this is a jquery version problem .on has replaced the .live because of some problems, those problems you can see on this link,

[What's the difference between jQuery .live() and .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on)

and you can write your code like this.

```
$(document).on('change','.myCheckbox:checkbox',function () {
// your code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.myCheckbox:checkbox', function() {

});
```

Btw, `live()` is deprecated as of jQuery version `1.7`, you should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.on` (upgrade your jQuery version to 1.7 for this).

The syntax is:

```
$('.yourCheckboxContainer').on('change', '.myCheckbox:checkbox', function() {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(document).on('change','.myCheckbox:checkbox',function () {
//..
}
```

As of jQuery version 1.7, the on() method is the new replacement for the `bind(), live()` and `delegate()` methods.

**Note:** Event handlers attached using the `on()` method will work for both current and FUTURE elements (like a new element created by a script)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

for jquery 1.7 further

```
$(document).on('change','.myCheckbox:checkbox',function () {
//..
});
```

for older version

```
$('.myCheckbox:checkbox').live('change',function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How I understood your problem, it's not about `.live` or `.on`. It's about if you first add the change listener with your existing code and then add new checkboxes to the page like

```
$(document).append($("<input type="checkbox" />"));
```

the change listener doesn't work with it.

This is normal, as the new checkbox doesn't exist when the listeners are added. You have to add the listeners to the new checkboxes when adding them.

```
$(document).append($("<input type="checkbox" />").change(whatever));
```