# Difference between document.on('event') and $().event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently got a problem that

```
$('.klass').change(function () { ... });
```

was not firing in some situations and found the solution on SO to use

```
$(document).on('change', '.klass', function () { ... });
```

instead. The explaination was that my element was created after declaration of the listener or something else was blocking it from firing.

So I should probably never use the first method? And use the second method for any event (click, change, ...):

```
$(document).on('event', 'jquery-selector', function () { ... });
```

Could someone please explain the difference between the two and possible gotchas.

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`change` calls `.on`

```
$().change = function( types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first method is fine, but as you said, you need to make sure that your element has been loaded into the DOM before you create your event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // dom has been loaded, now you can attach event handlers
})
```

As @wZVanG sort of said, `change()` is just sugar for calling `on`, there is no practical difference.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that the second one allows the use of multiple events.  Instead of saying

```
$('.klass').click(function(){
    //some content
});
$('.klass').change(function(){
    //same exact content, repeated
});
```

You can instead write

```
$('.klass').on('click change', function(){
    //some content, it applies to both now.
});
```

or you can use the (somewhat superfluous)

```
$(document).on('click change', '.klass', function(){
    //some content, it still applies to both.
});
```