# change from .live to .on, not populating data

Tags: jquery

i have a code

```
$("#client").live("change", function() {
    var clientId = $('select[name="client"]').val();
    if(!isEmpty(clientId)){
        batchDropDownPopulate(clientId, "batch");
    }
    $("#client2").val(clientId);
    var listItems = '<option value="">Please select</option>';
    $("#campaign").html(listItems);
});
```

which i changed to

```
 $('#client').on('change',  function() {
      var clientId = $(this).select2("val");
    if(!isEmpty(clientId)){
        batchDropDownPopulate(clientId, "batch");
    }
    $("#client2").val(clientId);
    var listItems = '<option value="">Please select</option>';
    $("#campaign").html(listItems);
});
```

But above code is not populating data or not working. Its not showing any error or not working on change event.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on

Comment: @AdhershMNair it worked

Comment: Ok @daisy......

Answer (score 0):

it was small change i wanted to do

```
 $(document).on('change','#client'  function() {
      var clientId = $(this).select2("val");
    if(!isEmpty(clientId)){
        batchDropDownPopulate(clientId, "batch");
    }
    $("#client2").val(clientId);
    var listItems = '<option value="">Please select</option>';
    $("#campaign").html(listItems);
});
```